# can't get variables in function

Tags: php

I have a translate system:

/phps/languages.php

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
if($lang == "en-us"){
    include_once("$root/site-languages/en-us.php"); // include en-us
}
```

this function:
/phps/date.php

```
function time_difference($date){

$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
include_once("$root/phps/languages.php");

echo $language_include_variable; // it is empty
```

and my page.php that will call date.php and date calls languages.php.

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
include_once("$root/phps/date.php");
```

The problem is the echo $language_include_variable is null.
any ideas?

Comment: Where is `$language_include_variable` defined? Can you show us in an example?

Comment: @DecentDabbler it is defined in the site-languages/en-us.php. like this: `$language_include_variable = "some text"`

Comment: anything from http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php ?

Comment: Where is `$lang` defined and is it actually `en-us`???

Comment: and where/how is $language_include_variable defined? check if you don't have a variable scoping also.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner in the en.us.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver in the en.us.php and it is working. but the function can't read it.

Comment: so it's a variable scope issue, had a feeling about that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and - being a possible duplicate here.

Comment: `time_difference()` is a function, so I would guess this is a Variable Scope issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly Your suggested duplicate question doesn't offer an explanation about this particular `include_once` issue. Therefore I'm voting to reopen this question.

Comment: @DecentDabbler Judging by the comment on the answer that suggests Scope Issues it does not do to badly.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to `include_once`. The file will only be included **once** in the lifetime of the script, and therefore be accessible in the function scope only once.

On subsequent calls of the function the file will not be included anymore and thus the variable will not be in the scope of the function anymore.

Comment: I removed all the _once and it works! thanks.